# Citation within sentence

Tags: citing

I'm searching for the code for that kind of citation:

> According to Smith [2009], the amount of.....

I am familiar with the normal use of `\cite`, but can't figure out how to use it within a sentence! I'm using `plain` as bibiliography style and no  citation management package.

I didn't find anything within `stackexchange`. If my question already exists, I would be grateful to get the hint!

Comment: with natbib, something like `citet` or `citep`, with biblatex it would be `\textcite`.

Comment: If you load the `natbib` package, `\cite` should produce a textual citation call-out, provided the bibliography style is capable of doing so. For sure, `plain` cannot produce textual citations, but `plainnat` can. Please do tell us which bibliography style you use, and please indicate whether you use a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]
An example with the natbib package.

Make a file called "biblio.bib" such as:

```
@book{Renardy,
    Author = {M. Renardy and R. C. Rogers},
    Edition = {Second},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations},
    Year = {2004}}
```

And your tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

According to \citet{Renardy}, the amount of...

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

The .bib file is especially easy to make with a program such as BibDesk.
The bibliographystyle (now plainnat) can be changed. Note that you need to typeset your file multiple times. Also the BibTex. In TexShop, under macros > Applescript there is a script called "Bibliography" that does the necessary typesets for you. 
Also see: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management.